# Stream AV Over LAN (NDI, H.264 ... ) to USB Capture Card?

Tags: stream, streaming, capture

I sell UC solutions that use PTZ cameras that can send their video stream to a decoder. The problem I've run into several times is that the customer does not want to install software to turn the stream around into a driver for Zoom or Teams. So I am looking for a solution that can take a video stream into a capture box and turn it around into a viewable driver that is plugable via USB 2.0, 3.0, 3.1 ... So,

Video stream -CAT6--RJ45---> Converter box ---USB---> CPU

I included an image below that may make more sense. I am aware of Magewell capture cards but they do not have a direct stream to usb solution.

NDI has virtual input but requires it to be installed on the destination computer. I'm looking for a direct connect no driver solution mainly for Windows based PCs.

[Signal Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrwq5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a combination of a HDMI-over-network hardware solution like:
https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=24281

Plus an USB HDMI capture card on the PC side like:
https://plugable.com/products/usbc-cap60

If there are multiple cameras, Windows won't know what to do with it by itself, however. Software-wise, it looks to Windows like you have multiple high-res webcams attached.

So while you don't need drivers -- it's using the standard webcam driver -- you do need software that can do stuff with multiple video streams, like OBS:
https://obsproject.com/

The Plugable USBC-CAP60 works with OBS.